# Who can choose the accepted answer in a community wiki question?

Tags: support, accepted-answer, community-wiki

The owner of a community wiki question is "community". Who has the privilege to choose the accepted answer in a community wiki question?

The original asker? Or anyone who has the privilege to edit community wiki questions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The choice of accepted answer is *always* with the author of the question.

Community Wiki questions don't count towards your accept rate (if that's what you're worried about), and no reputation is awarded to the asker or answerer when a community wiki answer is accepted ([Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297463/if-the-op-accepts-a-community-wiki-answer-do-they-get-2-rep#comment965041_297464)).

See [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/) for the rules on accept rate:

> - Questions must not be community wiki.
> - Questions must not be closed.
> - Questions must be more than 3 days old.
> - Questions must have at least 1 answer.
> - There must be at least four eligible questions as determined by the above rules, otherwise the statistic will not appear.