# If the OP accepts a community wiki answer, do they get +2 rep?

Tags: support, reputation, accepted-answer, community-wiki

Community Wiki answers give no reputation to the people who voted for them. They also [don't give](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145935/203101) the +15 of acceptance if they are marked as accepted.

But does the OP (of the question) get the normal +2 reputation points when they accept a CW answer?

Comment: I think they do get the +2. Why not? It's still an answer.

Comment: @ShadowWizard we were discussing this in a chatroom and nobody knew, so this was posted for science. We'll have the definitive answer in another 5 minutes when I can accept Chris's CW answer.

Comment: Sure, didn't say you shouldn't have asked this. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The questioner doesn't get a +2 for accepting a CW answer.

---

I have not been able to find a definitive answer, neither this answer:

[What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts/11741#11741)

nor this answer:

[No reputation from accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145934/no-reputation-from-accepted-answer/145935#145935)

help. They talk about is whether votes on or acceptance of the answer generate reputation for the **answerer**, but not whether the questioner gets their +2.

This answer:

[How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

does state:

> If you accept:
>
> - *a [community-wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/) answer*: no reputation is awarded.

which implies that no one gets any reputation, but the linked question is the "What are "Community Wiki" posts?" one I mention above.

I'm marking this answer as CW as a definitive test.

Comment: Confirmed: accepting this answer gave me no reputation.

Comment: faq answer updated now. :)